# Storing values locally using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have the following block of code

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let username = self.emailText.text
let password = self.passwordText.text
defaults.setValue(username, forKey: defaultsKeys.userKey)
defaults.setValue(password, forKey: defaultsKeys.passwordKey)
var u = defaults.stringForKey(defaultsKeys.userKey)
var p = defaults.stringForKey(defaultsKeys.passwordKey)
```

username and password are correct when setting.  However, when I pull them back u and p have the same value, and it's the password value.

I declare defaultKeys at the top of the page this way.

```
struct defaultsKeys {
    static let userKey = ""
    static let passwordKey = ""
}
```

I'm assuming there's a simple syntax error that I'm not seeing, because this seems like it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set different key names:

```
struct defaultsKeys {
    static let userKey = "userKey"
    static let passwordKey = "passwordKey"
}
```

Comment: I remember now, I did the same thing the last time I tried this initially.  I kept thinking the quotes was a default value.  Forgot it was a key.

Answer (score 3):

You have the same key for both, just set a different key for each one:

```
struct defaultsKeys {
    static let userKey = "USER_KEY"
    static let passwordKey = "PWD_KEY"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct defaultsKeys 
{
static let userKey = "userKey"
static let passwordKey = "passwordKey"
}
```